# Symfony: dynamically switching database connections for repositories

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entitymanager

I'm building a small test app with 2 databases and a login.

Both databases contain users and I wish to use both of them for login. I've setup a chain user provider for the login. I have entities for both user types and repositories. I also have two entity managers setup for them.

The problem I am facing is that I am unable to find a simple and clean solution to switch the connection for the entity manager within the second database's user repository.

Within a controller, I can call `$this->getDoctrine()->getManager('second')`, which will allow me to get the data from the second database. But for the login, it goes into the second database user repository, but keeps the default connection, which is the first database.

I've read a bit about dynamic database connection for Symfony, and the best I could come up with is creating a new entity manager, and replacing the user repository's `$this->_em` with the new one.

Code:

```php
public function createManager($user, $password, $dbname, $host, $port): EntityManager
    {
        $isDevMode = false;
        $userMappingPath = __DIR__ . '../Entity/Second';
        $paths = [$userMappingPath];
        $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration($paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false);
        $conn = [
            'driver' => 'pdo_mysql',
            'user' => $user,
            'password' => $password,
            'dbname' => $dbname,
            'host' => $host,
            'port' => $port,
            'server_version' => "8.0",
            'charset' => 'UTF8'
        ];
        // get the entitymanager with the new connection
        return EntityManager::create($conn, $config);
    }
```

And then in the second user repo:

```php
class SecondUserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $manager = new NewManager;
        $newManager = $manager->createManager('user', '12345678', 'database2', '127.0.0.1', '3306');
        
        
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
        $this->_em = $newManager;

    }
}
```

This way it works, though it feels like a suboptimal solution, since it would require to duplicate code whenever I have a repository that requires a non default connection.

Been stuck with this issue for over a day now and I can't figure it out.

Comment: You should be aware that when you have the same entity type mapped by more than one entity manager then the ServiceEntityRepository is completely broken.  As you have noticed, the first entity manager defined will always be used.  Look at the constructor code to see why.  At a minimum you need to extend from the EntityRepository class.  Your best bet might turn out to use two different user entities though that can be tricky as well.

Answer (score 0):

First create a new connection, e.g. "user" in doctrine.yaml. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Then try to do so:

```
class SecondUserRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        $newManager = $registry->getManager('user');       
        
        parent::__construct($registry, User::class);
        $this->_em = $newManager;

    }
}
```